# Tool in Visual Studio 2008 for helping with Localization

Tags: visual-studio, winforms, internationalization, vsx, extensibility

Does anyone have any recommendations of tools that can be of assistance with moving literal values into resource files for localization?

I've used a resharper plugin called RGreatX but was wondering if there is anything else out there.

It's one heck of a long manual process for moving the strings across and think there must be a better way! RGreatX is OK but could be a bit slicker I feel.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here's one:

http://www.codeplex.com/ResourceRefactoring

It'a actually a Microsoft "open source" Visual Studio(2005 and up) tool that integrates with the IDE.  You can easily replace every occurence of a string with a ressource reference with a few clicks.

Comment: Here is the VS2010 version: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/39ae29d3-81e1-43d4-9c48-fc9644869d84?SRC=VSIDE

Answer (score 1):

You may find [Zeta Resource Editor](http://www.codeplex.com/zetaResourceEditor/) useful too.

Answer (score 1):

ReSharper itself (5.0+) now has support for [localization](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/internationalization.html) which includes [moving strings to resource files](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/internationalization.html#Move_Strings_to_Resource_Files) and [highlighting localizabile strings](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/internationalization.html#Highlighting_Localizable_Strings).

Answer (score 0):

Try [Visual Localizer](https://visuallocalizer.codeplex.com) - you can batch-process whole code, select which strings may be localized and the tool will add them to a resource file and create a reference instead. Many other features easing localization are included.